# Certain jquery files are not getting load, on recording script with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

while recording J-meter scripts, certain J-query file is given error as file not loading, is the issue from developer side, or i need to make certain changes in my  scripts.

Comment: Hi. Kindly add some explanation and screenshots of what you are referring to, what you have done and what your query is to get the best of responses. If not it becomes highly difficult to understand and interpret the post

Answer (score 0):

Perform the same actions using browser without JMeter and look into its [Developer Tools](https://javascript.info/devtools) (especially in "Console" and "Network" tabs or equivalent)

[image]

If you can reproduce the issue - this is application problem and you should report it. If not - this is JMeter problem, most probably you misconfigured something or it's a [bug](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) in JMeter Proxy.

---

In general be aware that you **should not** be recording JavaScript files (as well as images, scripts, styles, fonts, and anything which does not belong to the domain you're testing), the corresponding filter goes in the first place in the "Requests Filtering" tab of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) when you create test plan using [Recording Template feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature).

[image]